# I want to write interface of dynamic array

Tags: typescript

`[["123456789",{"key": {id: '23456'}}], ["987654321",{"key": {id: '23456'}}]]`

I am working on purely typescript so i need to create an interface for above array. But i am so confused about it. How can i create interface for above array.

It would be appreciated if someone write it for me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe something like `interface ISampleInterface {
  id : string;
  data : {
    bleDevice : <typeof Device>
  }
}`

and usage `ISampleInterface[]`

Comment: Thanks! But i don't think, because it's an array of arrays. Not an object. And inside array, id is dynamic not static.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the types for the array as follow:

```
type Root = [string, Root2][]

interface Root2 {
  key: Key
}

interface Key {
  id: string
}

const arr: Root = [
  [
    "123456789",
    {
      "key": {
        "id": "23456"
      }
    }
  ],
  [
    "987654321",
    {
      "key": {
        "id": "23456"
      }
    }
  ]
]
```